# .asp Includes and http requests

Tags: performance, asp-classic, httprequest

Here's a question, I'm quite new with server side scripting specially .ASP as I mostly do front end, we are currently building a single page app that have over 18 different sections, I though for better code organization and cleanness I'm planning on separating all sections on their own .asp file and then just #include them on the main .asp file. My question is, will each #include be counted as a separate http request? will this approach affect performance?

Any enlightenment to this fool will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this really `.asp`? Or is it `.aspx`? You need to tag the question correctly. Why did you tag it as `httprequest`? What framework are you using for your single page app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include's takes place server side and any VBScript in it is executed server side as well unless you specifically tell it to run client side.  So no, it will not cause a separate http request and the performance would depend on the execution time of the VBScript and the rendering time (depending on the size of the html) served to the browser.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.